# Moonlight not working on firefox or chromium - Ubuntu 11.04

Tags: 11.04, moonlight

I'm trying to watch my `sky films` but I need `silverlight` of course. I have tried downloading `moonlight 4` on `Chromium` - says: `cannot unzip package so does not finish download`
In the latest `Firefox` of course it's not compatible (yet?)

---

I'm new to Ubuntu,I can follow instructions

Is there anyway I can get around this?

Answer (score 1):

Moonlight 4.0 is compatible with Firefox 12.0 (Latest stable release for Ubuntu). To install follow these steps:

- Open Firefox and visit Moonlight download [page](http://go-mono.com/moonlight/download.aspx)
- Select your the architecture of you system (32bit or 64bit)
- Click on download button, Firefox will show you a confirmation box click allow.

[image]

[image]

- Click on "Install Now" on the installation dialog box.

[image]

- Upon completion of download click on restart. That's it!

[image]

After restart you'll see Silverlight plug-in listed under installed plug-ins.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Move the .mozilla folder from- /home/your user name/.mozilla to a different name like `mozilla_old`.

Then try installing the moonlight again.

Caution : deleting .mozilla will remove everthing. I mean your addons and bookmarks.

Comment: Since there has been a bit of fulrry in chat about the danger of this answer, I've revised it a bit. With that said, how would this help?